# Google contacts gdata (Java) fails on No parser for content type:application-xml[application/xml]

Tags: java, gdata, google-contacts-api

Recently, a 2 days ago we started to experience exception in google gdata client in Java, when trying to access contacts (feed : /m8/feeds/contacts/default/full). The exception is :

```
com.google.gdata.util.ParseException: No parser for content type:application-xml[application/xml]
     at com.google.gdata.client.Service.parseResponseData(Service.java:2142)
     at com.google.gdata.client.Service.parseResponseData(Service.java:2098)
     at com.google.gdata.client.Service.getFeed(Service.java:1136)
     at com.google.gdata.client.Service.getFeed(Service.java:1077)
     at com.google.gdata.client.GoogleService.getFeed(GoogleService.java:676)
     at com.google.gdata.client.Service.getFeed(Service.java:1034)
```

Did some sniffing with Wireshark and in the google documentation I see that correct responses should come with Content type : application/atom+xml but failed responses from google now coming with Content Type : application/xml. 
Seems that something changed in google, and now it's returnes not correct content type and our code stopped to work (it was working fine for few years).

Need to say that part of the google app tenants (our customers) still working fine (with the same code) , but some parts of the customers is failing.

Is there any possible workaround for that issue ?

Thanks

Comment: We are also observing this behaviour in our application.

Comment: I opened a ticket in Google tracker https://issuetracker.google.com/u/0/issues/113122339

Comment: it is frustrating to see no reply, our application is getting a lot of errors.

Comment: Someone answered in the ticket I've opened that google confirmed the issue.

Comment: Exactly the same problem here. Something was changed on Google side.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was fixed on Google side, so there is nothing to do on our side.

Comment: Yes, but we did also work around to continue to work