# Strange error for almost a month from Google Contacts API

Tags: google-api, gdata, google-contacts-api

We started to see strange error where google contacts gdata lib (Java) failed to parse the response coming from google (accessing google contacts feed).

The error on extended property :

```
com.google.gdata.util.ParseException: [Line 1, Column 10833, element gd:extendedProperty] exactly one of g:extendedProperty/@value, XML is required
```

Or

```
com.google.gdata.util.ParseException: [Line 2, Column 3234, element gd:email] g:email/@address is required.
```

In the exception of g:extendedProperty, seems (after sniffing) that extended property in the xml looks :

```
< gd:extendedProperty name='google_apps_sync'/ >
```

missing value, there's only name.

When we asked customer to contact google support (this is customer's contacts) google support suggested them to reinstall our app (very strange, we're a cloud service), we suggested to the customer to delete this problematic contact (found in sniffing) and re-create it again and this helped.

Looks like google is doing something with contacts and this caused them to respond with incorrect data (this maybe also related to [Google contacts gdata (Java) fails on No parser for content type:application-xml[application/xml]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51995274/google-contacts-gdata-java-fails-on-no-parser-for-content-typeapplication-xml))

And also looks like google support not really knows what to do and suggest very strange solutions.

Googlers , please advise.
Thanks

Comment: I suggest you file again another bug report or [reopen the ticket](https://issuetracker.google.com/u/0/issues/113122339) you've filed before.

Comment: I did : https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/116253490